# RESTful mediatype if no xsd is present

Tags: rest

I'm new to RESTful Webservices.  I've started developing a RESTful Webservice that has a single method that accepts a request object and returns a response object.  Both the request and response object belong to an XSD(say like `employee_v1_xsd`).  My method consumes an `EmployeeRequest` and produces or returns an `EmployeeResponse`.  This is what I have for my method declaration.

```
@Consumes("application/vnd.employee_v1_xsd+xml")
@Produces("application/vnd.employee_v1_xsd+xml")
```

Where `employee_v1_xsd` is the xsd that contains all the schema definitions that my REST WS will be using. And in the WADL I've given the same media type specification.

Later, I've to add another method that consumes another Webservice.  Due to some reasons(unknown to me), I just got only a WSDL of the Webservice which I'm going to consume.  I could generate all the required request and response objects that is needed to call the WS using the WSDL via jaxb's xjc command.

My question here is :

1. I've to pass certain request and get a response object on calling the Webservice(Say like TaxDetailsRequest and TaxDetailsResponse).  since i dont have any xsd of the Webservice which i'm going to call from my REST webservice, what should be given as the media type just above the method declaration and in the WADL?
2. It would be very much helpfull, if someone could point me to a good tutorial or something to understand this REST media type.